# How to increment value of global variable in assembly in linux

Tags: assembly, x86-64

I am going through the assembly implementation of AES algorithm to understand, how sbox and lookup table are implemented/accessed. 
Theoretically I know, AES uses 10 rounds when key length=128bits.

There is one part where one loop of 200 lines of code (representation of AES rounds) is executed.

```
_x86_64_AES_decrypt_compact:


.Ldec_loop_compact:

xorl    0(%r15),%eax
xorl    4(%r15),%ebx
xorl    8(%r15),%ecx
xorl    12(%r15),%edx
leaq    16(%r15),%r15
.
.
.
xorl    %r12d,%ecx
movq    256(%r14),%r13
xorl    %r8d,%ebx
xorl    %r11d,%edx

jmp .Ldec_loop_compact
```

I want to increase a global variable's (i.e. round_var) value by 1 every time one round of AES is completed.
So at the end of AES operation on 1 block (16bytes), the variable's value will be 10 and 
at the end of AES operation on 2 block (2x16bytes), the variable's value will be 20.

```
.globl round_var 
round_var:
.long 0

_x86_64_AES_decrypt_compact:


.Ldec_loop_compact:
.
.
.
;increase round_var by 1 
.
.
.
jmp .Ldec_loop_compact
```

To increase round_var by 1 , I tried following approaches

```
64bit :
        movq    round_var(%rip), %rax
        addq    $1, %rax
        movq    %rax, round_var(%rip)

32bit :
        movl    round_var(%rip), %eax
        addl    $1, %eax
        movl    %eax, round_var(%rip)
```

As all of eax,ebx,ecx,edx are used inside that loop, I just added those lines before the updation of %eax (or %rax) register so it won't effect AES operation.

After addition of those lines, I am successfully able to execute following commands to build customized openssl. It means the lines are added at correct place during compile/assemble time.

```
make
sudo make install
```

However, I got segmentation fault while trying to perform AES decryption operation. This indicates something went wrong at those lines codes at runtime.

I suspect **%rip** of `movl    round_var(%rip), %eax` is causing this segmentation fault.

It will be great if anyone help me to resolve the above issue or to increment the global variable round_var by 1 using assembly instruction ?

I am using Ubuntu-16.04 , Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7200U CPU @ 2.50GHz and Openssl-1.0.2n

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't put your variable into the `.text` section because it is read-only. Also, why tag it as `arm` if you are using x86-64?

Comment: @Jester, thanks for your prompt reply. Where to put variable then ?

Comment: @bholanath Put them into `.data` if they are initialized, to `.bss` otherwise.

Comment: @fuz: `.bss` is zero-initialized, not indeterminate.  You can reliably use it for variables like `static int foo = 0;`, and compilers of course do that.  I don't like the term "uninitialized" for zero-init, because in other contexts (like local vars in C) the same word is used to mean indeterminate.  e.g. "variable bar is used uninitialized in function blah blah"

Comment: @fuz, thank you. I got the above error as I was trying to modify the variable which was declared at read-only section. By declaring the variable at .bss or .data section solves the problem. What I did as follows- .bss
.global          round_var
round_var:
.long 0

I don't know how to declare global initialized variable at .data section

Comment: @bholanath The same way: `.data ; .global round_var ; round_var: .long 0x1234`

Comment: @fuz, thank you. you can write this as answer (either in .bss or .data ), I will accept as it solved my problem (segmentation is caused as I was trying to modify the variable which was declared at read-only section).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Static variables should be placed in the `.data` section.  To do this, write:

```
        .data                 # enter the data section
        .align 4              # align to four bytes
var:    .long 1234            # assemble a 32 bit word with value 1234
```

you might also want to specify the following to aid debugging:

```
        .type var,@object     # var refers to an object
        .size var,4           # var occupies 4 bytes of storage
```

If the variable initially has the value zero, you can optionally place it in the `.bss` section to save space in the binary.  The `.bss` section does not occupy space in the binary and is filled with zeroes at runtime.

```
        .bss                  # enter the bss section
        .align 4              # align to four bytes
var:    .space 4              # allocate four bytes for var
```

Similarly to the previous approach, you might also want to specify symbol size and type for better debugging.

As a shorthand for this, you may write

```
        .lcomm var,4          # align four bytes in .bss for var
```

A third option is defining the variable as a common symbol.  This causes all variables with the same name from other translation units to be merged with this one and is useful for creating global variables.  Simply write

```
        .comm var,4           # defines var to be a common symbol of size 4
```